# Android APP with kivy error: I python : Message: 'Unable to open directory </>'

Tags: python, android, python-2.7, kivy, buildozer

Ive created an app for android and i used buildozer to create the apk file.
When I opened the app on my smartphone I got a blackscreen.
So I checked the log with: adb logcat -s python and got the following error:

```
08-04 21:35:14.383 16483 16559 I python : --- Logging error --- 
08-04 21:35:14.385 16483 16559 I python : Traceback (most recent call last): 
08-04 21:35:14.386 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/filechooser.py", line 852, in _generate_file_entries 
08-04 21:35:14.386 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/filechooser.py", line 870, in _add_files 
08-04 21:35:14.387 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/filechooser.py", line 170, in listdir 
08-04 21:35:14.387 16483 16559 I python : PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/' 
08-04 21:35:14.388 16483 16559 I python :
08-04 21:35:14.389 16483 16559 I python : During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 
08-04 21:35:14.389 16483 16559 I python :
08-04 21:35:14.389 16483 16559 I python : Traceback (most recent call last): 
08-04 21:35:14.391 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/logging/init.py", line 1083, in emit 
08-04 21:35:14.391 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/logging/init.py", line 927, in format 
08-04 21:35:14.392 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/logger.py", line 291, in format 
08-04 21:35:14.392 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy 
08-04 21:35:14.392 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct 
08-04 21:35:14.393 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy 
08-04 21:35:14.393 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict 
08-04 21:35:14.394 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy 
08-04 21:35:14.394 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/copy.py", line 210, in _deepcopy_tuple 
08-04 21:35:14.394 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/copy.py", line 210, in 
08-04 21:35:14.395 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy 
08-04 21:35:14.395 16483 16559 I python : TypeError: cannot pickle 'traceback' object 
08-04 21:35:14.395 16483 16559 I python : Call stack: 
08-04 21:35:14.398 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 154, in 
08-04 21:35:14.398 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py", line 955, in run 
08-04 21:35:14.399 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp 
08-04 21:35:14.399 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 339, in mainloop 
08-04 21:35:14.399 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 379, in idle 
08-04 21:35:14.399 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/clock.py", line 733, in tick 
08-04 21:35:14.400 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/clock.py", line 776, in post_idle 
08-04 21:35:14.400 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/filechooser.py", line 711, in _update_files 
08-04 21:35:14.400 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/filechooser.py", line 731, in _create_files_entries 
08-04 21:35:14.400 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fileencrypt1/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/filechooser.py", line 855, in _generate_file_entries 
08-04 21:35:14.400 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/logging/init.py", line 1481, in exception 
08-04 21:35:14.400 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/logging/init.py", line 1475, in error 
08-04 21:35:14.401 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/logging/init.py", line 1589, in _log 
08-04 21:35:14.401 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/logging/init.py", line 1599, in handle 
08-04 21:35:14.401 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/logging/init.py", line 1661, in callHandlers 
08-04 21:35:14.401 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/logging/init.py", line 952, in handle 
08-04 21:35:14.401 16483 16559 I python : File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/logging/init.py", line 1091, in emit 
08-04 21:35:14.402 16483 16559 I python : Message: 'Unable to open directory </>' 
08-04 21:35:14.402 16483 16559 I python : Arguments: ()
```

I would be happy if someone could help me with this error

Comment: do you use path `</>`? There is no path `</>` but `/`. But Android may block access to some folders for security reason.

Comment: in some place in error message I see `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/'` - as I said Android may block access to some folders for security reason and you may have to use only some subfolders.

Comment: after formatting error message I see problem makes `listdir` - so don't use `listdir()` for folder `/`